# File Share is keep on loading not showing the files in Azure Storage Explorer

Tags: azure-storage-explorer

in Azure Storage Explorer i connected to file share through shared access signature(SAS) URI method. after connected, no files are showing under File Shares folder as shown in the image it is keep on loading.

[image]

and popping the error message as below after waiting for long time

[image]

i'm using Windows 7, Azure Storage Explorer version : 1.10.1, and  i have .net 4.0 Framework installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may occur due to several reasons like Network issue/ Proxy/subscription/updates/Permissions.

There a few reasons you may be seeing this error: Firstly,  I would suggest to try the troubleshooting steps mentioned here:

Delete data from "%appData/StorageExplorer" folder or entire folder from your machine. After deleting when you launch storage explorer you will be prompted to re-enter your credentials.

The uninstall process does not remove all of the files in the local storage, and so I found that on Windows at least if I uninstall MASE and remove the folders that are in C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer and reinstall, 
If you are connected to Azure through a proxy, verify that your proxy settings are correct. If you were granted access to a resource from the owner of the subscription or account, verify that you have read or list permissions for that resource. 
Connection String Does Not Have Complete Configuration Settings

Refer the following Storage Explorer troubleshooting documentation and let us know if you need further assistance: [Unable to Retrieve Children](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-explorer-troubleshooting?tabs=Windows%2C1904#unable-to-retrieve-children-error-message)

If the issue still persist un-install and reinstall the latest v[ersion 1.11.2](https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/releases)

It would also be worth checking if port 445 is open, since File shares are SMB based, port 445 has to be open. Several Internet service providers block it, so it's also worth testing whether it is open and you can connect to it.  you can use the following tool to test it: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Troubleshooting-tool-for-a9fa1fe5